# My List View activity is just going blank without any noticeable errors

Tags: android, json, listview

I have imported all the necessary statements,
checked the code,
the json array from mySql is getting to the app correctly.
The list view id is correct, xml layouts are fine, there were a few erros in the logcat but i couldnt understand them . For eg -:" ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument"
Why does the activity still go blank?
Someone please help with explaination

This is my ListShower class:

```
public class ListShower extends ListActivity {

    private static final String URL_GET_WORKS = "link";

    private List<Work> workList;
    private WorkListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView listView = getListView();
        workList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new WorkListAdapter(this, workList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Make HTTP request to get list of works
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL_GET_WORKS,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                                String companyName = jsonObject.getString("companyName");
                                String address = jsonObject.getString("address");
                                String contract = jsonObject.getString("contract");

                                Work work = new Work(id, companyName, address, contract);
                                workList.add(work);
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error retrieving works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("ListShower", "Error retrieving works", error);

                    }
                }
        );

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        // Set click listener for list items
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Work clickedWork = workList.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ListShower.this, WorkDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("companyName", clickedWork.getCompanyName());
                intent.putExtra("address", clickedWork.getAddress());
                intent.putExtra("contract", clickedWork.getContract());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my adapter class :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Work work = getItem(position);
    TextView nameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyNameTextView);
    TextView emailTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
    TextView phoneNumberTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.contractTextView);

    nameTextView.setText(work.getCompanyName());
    emailTextView.setText(work.getAddress());
    phoneNumberTextView.setText(work.getContract());

    return convertView;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Work clickedUser = workList.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WorkDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("companyName", clickedUser.getCompanyName());
    intent.putExtra("address", clickedUser.getAddress());
    intent.putExtra("contract", clickedUser.getContract());
    // Add any other details you want to pass

    getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Whats your `adapter` code?

Comment: I added the adapter class